# How to add a bitbucket cloned project into already installed Magento project

Tags: php, magento, xampp, bitbucket

I have successfully installed *Magento-2 community edition* in my **localhost** and my server is running on **xampp**. My database is also running as it should be. This project is working just fine.

I have cloned a Magneto project from bitbucket into my **htdocs** directory of **xampp**.

*Now, I want to run that cloned project in my localhost.*
Should I merge the cloned project with my existing installed Magento project or I should install it again. The issue with installing it again is that it doesn't have any setup folder through which I could install it.

As I am new to Magento I don't know much about it. Care to help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get the same version of Magento installed as of the downloaded project. Then in the downloading steps, you can easily integrate the new code.